# binding a collection/list to a kendo mvc grid column

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I am trying to bind a list of comments to a column, but it doesn't display anything. I am using an inline Client Template to quickly test it, but no luck. I know for sure there are Comments in the model, but it seems to think that the Comments is undefined or null. Below is my code:

```
    @{
    var grid = Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(l => l.Name);
            columns.Bound(l => l.Description);
            columns.Bound(l => l.Comments).ClientTemplate("# if(Comments) { for(var i=0; i<Comments.length; i++) {# #=Comments[i].Comment# #}}# ").Title("Comments");

        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 850px;" })
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
        .Filterable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
         );
    grid.Render();
}
```

Comment: What is the end-goal here? How do you want your comments to show? The way you write your template (since it doesn't lead to an error) I would expect it to show the last list item comment. Do you want to concatenate all comments to one?

Comment: yes, using a comma.

Comment: It shouldn't be easier to concatenate those comments in the controller/service when yore pulling the data from? and just return a simple string value.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a JavaScript function and calling it in your client template. Also, it will be easier to debug.

```
function displayComments(data) {
    return $.map(data.Comments, function (e) { return e.Comment; }).join(", ");
}
```

In your Grid:

```
columns.Bound(l => l.Comments).ClientTemplate("#= displayComments(data) #").Title("Comments");
```